# UTF-8 encoding issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I'm upgrading a Rails app from 2 to 3. I have a Mysql table with data like this:

```
Â½â€ x 12â€ Rebar          
14â€™ LVL 1-3/4" X 11-7/8"
```

When running Rails 2 these names look normal (`½” x 12” Rebar` and 
`14’ LVL 1-3/4" X 11-7/8"`), but when I run my Rails 3 branch Ruby is using the same form as the database.

My guess is Rails 2 ignores the table encoding for another instead. Somehow I need to force the encoding, not convert it. I fixed this issue for one string through use of `<string>.encode().force_encoding()` but I'd rather fix the root cause in the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3901565/525478 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1294117/525478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I identified all the characters that were breaking down and replaced them with Find-Replaces and then reimported the data into a utf-8 table. On a whim I tried to use this data in the live environment and the live environment display broke in a similar way even though the modified data looked great in development.

Diffing the old data and the new data reveals how messed up the data is:

```
Â½â€<U+009D> x 12â€<U+009D> Rebar
```

becomes

```
½\" x 12\" Rebar
```

I'm guessing the encoding Rails 2 is using isn't UTF-8.